# What to do when there's no UI in Uncle Bob Clean Architecture

Tags: android, architecture, clean-architecture

I'm starting to apply the [Uncle Bob Clear Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) in commercially Android to the projects I'm working with.

There are some blind spots that I don't know how to tidy my code, and in this case there's no UI.

My example would be a dependency that stays as a Singleton containing miscellaneous content:

---

**DATA LAYER**

`ContentService.kt` has the interface for Retrofit

`ContentRepository.kt` has the repository that connects with the service

---

---

**DOMAIN LAYER**

`ContentUseCase.kt` contains the use case I'll use to transform into business logic and test it

---

Now, I have a file called `ContentManager.kt` that holds my information in a Singleton:

```
class ContentManager {

    object Singleton {
        var instance : ContentManager? = null
    }

    var todaysRastafariDay : String? = null
    var imageRastafariDayUrl: String? = null

    fun setRastafaryDay(day: String, imageUrl: String) {
        todaysRastafariDay = day
        imageRastafariDayUrl = imageUrl
    }

    companion object {
        fun getInstance() : ContentManager {
            if (Singleton.instance == null) {
                Singleton.instance = ContentManager()
            }

            return Singleton.instance!!
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question now? Clean architecture in general does not require an UI